# How I can set timings properly with 2 updating scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to spawn objects on the scene when the beat timer is bigger than time set in advance and I want to spawn some object at the same time.

I've expected that objects will spawn normaly when the time comes, but I have multiple issues at the same time: some objects spawn not at the same time, the first object out of multiple doesn't spawn and if I will try to spawn only one object it will NOT spawn.

I've tried to get rid of secondary beat check, but as I expected, it started to spawn multiple objects.

I'm using Unity 2019.4.35f1

This is the code of the spawner:

```
public class SpawnerScanner : MonoBehaviour
{
    float ScrSpd;
    float bpmSongTime = 0f;
    int noteIndex = 0;
    int arrIndex;
    GameObject notePrefab;
    bool isEnemy, isPlayer, isSet;
    Sprite noteSprite;
    void Update()
    {
        if(!isSet){
            ScrSpd = SongManager.instance.scrollSpeed;
            if(transform.parent.gameObject.name == "EnemySpawners"){
                isEnemy = true;
            } else {
                isEnemy = false;
            }
            for(int ID = 0; ID < transform.parent.transform.childCount; ID++){
                if(gameObject.name == transform.parent.transform.GetChild(ID).gameObject.name){
                    arrIndex = ID;
                }
            }

            notePrefab = SongManager.instance.prefab;
            noteSprite = SongManager.instance.Notes7K[arrIndex];
            isSet = true;
        } else {
            bpmSongTime = SongManager.instance.songPositionInBeats;
            noteIndex = SongManager.instance.nextIndex;

            if(SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].ArrID == arrIndex){ // && bpmSongTime > SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].time - (4f / ScrSpd)
                if(SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].isEnemy == isEnemy){
                    GameObject spawned = Instantiate(notePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    NoteController script = spawned.GetComponent<NoteController>();
                    script.Spawner = gameObject;
                    script.Remover = GameObject.Find("EnemyArrowsHolder").transform.GetChild(arrIndex).gameObject;
                    script.sr.sprite = noteSprite;
                    script.RealBeat = bpmSongTime;
                    script.SetBeat = SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].time;
                }

                if(SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].isEnemy != isEnemy && SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].isPlayer == true){
                    GameObject spawned = Instantiate(notePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    NoteController script = spawned.GetComponent<NoteController>();
                    script.Spawner = gameObject;
                    script.Remover = GameObject.Find("ArrowsHolder").transform.GetChild(arrIndex).gameObject;
                    script.sr.sprite = noteSprite;
                    script.RealBeat = bpmSongTime;
                    script.SetBeat = SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].time;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the main controller script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SongManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite[] Notes7K;
    public static SongManager instance;
    public float scrollSpeed;
    AudioSource MusicPlayer;
    AudioSource VoicesPlayer;
    public float bpm;
    float songPosition;
    public float songPositionInBeats;
    public float secPerBeat;
    float dspTimeSong;
    public List<Note> SN = new List<Note>();
    public int nextIndex;
    
    void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
        MusicPlayer = GameObject.Find("MusicHolder").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        VoicesPlayer = GameObject.Find("VoiceHolder").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        secPerBeat = 60f / bpm;
        dspTimeSong = (float)AudioSettings.dspTime;
        MusicPlayer.Play();
        VoicesPlayer.Play();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        songPosition = (float) (AudioSettings.dspTime - dspTimeSong);
        songPositionInBeats = songPosition / secPerBeat;

        if(nextIndex < SN.Count && songPositionInBeats > SN[nextIndex].time - (4f / scrollSpeed)){
            nextIndex++;
        }
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Note
{
    public bool isEnemy, isPlayer;
    public int ArrID;
    public float time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the Main controller, you have an int "nextIndex" describing which note should be spawned this frame.
in the spawner, you check each frame if the "noteIndex"(the same as the nextIndex) corresponds to a note that should be spawned from this spawner.
this causes **many Issues**

1. you will never truly be able to spawn 2 notes on the same frame as the Index can only ever be one number per frame.
2. because you are relying on the 2 updates to line up like Main Contoller changes nextIndex at the beginning of the frame > Spawner grabs the change and spawns the note. you are essentially passing control to which thread picks up the tasks first. aka Asking for problems.

instead you could invoke an Event each time it is time to spawn a note, which would pass control to all the spawners to check if they need to be involved.

1. Stuff to add to Main Controller

add the Unity Events Name Space

```
using UnityEngine.Events;
```

add a public UnityEvent variable at the class level

```
UnityEvent m_SpawnNote;
```

in start Initialize it.

```
m_SpawnNote = new UnityEvent();
```

and Invoke that Event whenever you change Indexes

```
m_SpawnNote.Invoke();
```

make a new public method so that your spawners can subscribe to the event

```
public void AddSpawnListener(SpawnerScanner scriptToAdd)
{
    //Very Dangerous if the scriptToAdd does not have the 
    //SpawnNote method you will get an exception
    m_SpawnNote.AddListener(scriptToAdd.SpawnNote);
}
```

Your Script should now look like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class SongManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite[] Notes7K;
    public static SongManager instance;
    public float scrollSpeed;
    AudioSource MusicPlayer;
    AudioSource VoicesPlayer;
    public float bpm;
    float songPosition;
    public float songPositionInBeats;
    public float secPerBeat;
    float dspTimeSong;
    public List<Note> SN = new List<Note>();
    public int nextIndex;
    UnityEvent m_SpawnNote;
    
    void Start()
    {
        m_SpawnNote = new UnityEvent();
        instance = this;
        MusicPlayer = GameObject.Find("MusicHolder").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        VoicesPlayer = GameObject.Find("VoiceHolder").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        secPerBeat = 60f / bpm;
        dspTimeSong = (float)AudioSettings.dspTime;
        MusicPlayer.Play();
        VoicesPlayer.Play();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        songPosition = (float) (AudioSettings.dspTime - dspTimeSong);
        songPositionInBeats = songPosition / secPerBeat;

        if(nextIndex < SN.Count && songPositionInBeats > SN[nextIndex].time - (4f / scrollSpeed)){
            nextIndex++;
            m_SpawnNote.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public void AddSpawnListener(SpawnerScanner scriptToAdd)
    {
        //Very Dangerous if the scriptToAdd does not have the 
        //SpawnNote method you will get an exception
        m_SpawnNote.AddListener(scriptToAdd.SpawnNote);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Note
{
    public bool isEnemy, isPlayer;
    public int ArrID;
    public float time;
}
```

2. Stuff to Add to the Spawner Script

first let's add the spawner as a listener to the event so under if(!isSet) add

```
SongManager.instance.AddSpawnListener(this);
```

now all we need to do is put all the note spawning stuff within the public method **SpawnNote**.

```
public void SpawnNote()
{
    if(SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].ArrID == arrIndex) // && bpmSongTime > SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].time - (4f / ScrSpd)
    {
        if(SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].isEnemy == isEnemy){
            GameObject spawned = Instantiate(notePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            NoteController script = spawned.GetComponent<NoteController>();
            script.Spawner = gameObject;
            script.Remover = GameObject.Find("EnemyArrowsHolder").transform.GetChild(arrIndex).gameObject;
            script.sr.sprite = noteSprite;
            script.RealBeat = bpmSongTime;
            script.SetBeat = SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].time;
        }

        if(SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].isEnemy != isEnemy && SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].isPlayer == true)
        {
            GameObject spawned = Instantiate(notePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            NoteController script = spawned.GetComponent<NoteController>();
            script.Spawner = gameObject;
            script.Remover = GameObject.Find("ArrowsHolder").transform.GetChild(arrIndex).gameObject;
            script.sr.sprite = noteSprite;
            script.RealBeat = bpmSongTime;
            script.SetBeat = SongManager.instance.SN[noteIndex].time;
        }
    }
}
```

now you are going to be telling the Spawners when to spawn their respective notes. but this still doesn't fix the issue of only one note being able to spawn per frame so I am going to add a for loop to fix that, I am not going to describe everything, but if you are interested, just ask.

Use This Main Controller Script Instead

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class SongManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite[] Notes7K;
    public static SongManager instance;
    public float scrollSpeed;
    AudioSource MusicPlayer;
    AudioSource VoicesPlayer;
    public float bpm;
    float songPosition;
    public float songPositionInBeats;
    public float secPerBeat;
    float dspTimeSong;
    public List<Note> SN = new List<Note>();
    public int nextIndex;
    UnityEvent m_SpawnNote;
    
    void Start()
    {
        m_SpawnNote = new UnityEvent();
        instance = this;
        MusicPlayer = GameObject.Find("MusicHolder").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        VoicesPlayer = GameObject.Find("VoiceHolder").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        secPerBeat = 60f / bpm;
        dspTimeSong = (float)AudioSettings.dspTime;
        MusicPlayer.Play();
        VoicesPlayer.Play();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        songPosition = (float) (AudioSettings.dspTime - dspTimeSong);
        songPositionInBeats = songPosition / secPerBeat;

        for(int i = nextIndex; i < SN.Count && songPositionInBeats > SN[i].time - (4f / scrollSpeed); i++)
        {
            m_SpawnNote.Invoke();
            nextIndex++;
        }
    }

    public void AddSpawnListener(SpawnerScanner scriptToAdd)
    {
        //Very Dangerous if the scriptToAdd does not have the 
        //SpawnNote method you will get an exception
        m_SpawnNote.AddListener(scriptToAdd.SpawnNote);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Note
{
    public bool isEnemy, isPlayer;
    public int ArrID;
    public float time;
}
```

Comment: You have forgot the '''GetComponent<>()''' in AddListener of SongManager. After this addition my game started working. But as you said, I'm using '''for''' and it's impossible to make spawn several notes at the same time. So how I can make it synchronized?

Comment: Actually, on second thought, we could pass a reference to the script instead of the GameObject, thanks for spotting that I didn't use an IDE to check. I am confused by the second part of your question? does the for I added not work because that should spawn each note that needs to this frame. also do you have a github so I can get a better Idea of the source code, Love Rhythm Games btw

Comment: The thing is that I need to spawn not only one note at the time. '''for''' loop is not made for this. Also, I've tried to make a time list for each spawner, but it spawned every frame and at the same position.
Also, there is the code: https://github.com/Pikramag/Rhythm-Game-Sample

Comment: The **for** loop is designed to loop through the list until it hits a Note in the SN list that is not supposed to spawn at this time; It should do that all on the one frame. this is assuming a few things: 1. The list Is ordered by Time, 2. notes that are supposed to spawn at the same time actually share the same time value. an Issue that might come up is that SongManger might change the **nextIndex** many times before SpawnScanner can read it, and we might want to either Async it or pass the index as an argument if that is the case. let me know from your tests. thanks for the github too!